# Subsetting data set to only retain the mean

Tags: r

[image: Data]

Please see attached image of dataset.

What are the different ways to only retain a single value for each 'Month'? I've got a bunch of data points and would only need to retain, say, the mean value.

Many thanks

Comment: Perhaps, you need `aggregate(dat, index(dat), FUN = mean)`

Comment: The aggregate function works perfectly! Thank you and all the best.

Comment: I thought your data is xts or zoo format.  You should have told me earlier that it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different way of using the `aggregate()` function.

> ```
> > aggregate(Temp ~ Month, data=airquality, FUN = mean)
>   Month     Temp
> 1     5 65.54839
> 2     6 79.10000
> 3     7 83.90323
> 4     8 83.96774
> 5     9 76.90000
> ```

Comment: This is very simple and remarkably intuitive. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can group by the `index` of dataset, use that in `aggregate` (from `base R`) to get the `mean`

```
aggregate(dat, index(dat), FUN = mean)
```

NB: Here, we assumed that the dataset is `xts` or `zoo` format.  If the dataset have a month column, then use

```
aggregate(dat, list(dat$Month), FUN = mean)
```

Comment: Where does index() function come from?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

#example data from airquality:

aq<-as_data_frame(airquality)

aq$mydate<-lubridate::ymd(paste0(2018, "-", aq$Month, "-", aq$Day))
```

> ```
> > aq
> # A tibble: 153 x 7
>    Ozone Solar.R  Wind  Temp Month   Day mydate    
>    <int>   <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <date>    
>  1    41     190  7.40    67     5     1 2018-05-01
>  2    36     118  8.00    72     5     2 2018-05-02
>  3    12     149 12.6     74     5     3 2018-05-03
> ```

```
aq %>% 
    group_by("Month" = month(mydate)) %>% 
    summarize("Mean_Temp" = mean(Temp, na.rm=TRUE))
```

[Summarize](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html) can return multiple [summary functions](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf):

```
aq %>% 
    group_by("Month" = month(mydate)) %>% 
    summarize("Mean_Temp" = mean(Temp, na.rm=TRUE), 
              "Num" = n(), 
              "SD" = sd(Temp, na.rm=TRUE))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 4
>   Month Mean_Temp   Num    SD
>   <dbl>     <dbl> <int> <dbl>
> 1  5.00      65.5    31  6.85
> 2  6.00      79.1    30  6.60
> 3  7.00      83.9    31  4.32
> 4  8.00      84.0    31  6.59
> 5  9.00      76.9    30  8.36
> ```

[Lubridate](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/) [Cheatsheet](https://rawgit.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/master/lubridate.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

A data.table answer:

```
# load libraries
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

setDT(dt) 

dt[, .(meanValue = mean(value, na.rm =TRUE)), by = .(monthDate = floor_date(dates, "month"))]
```

Where `dt` has at least columns `value` and `dates`.